# Java String.replaceAll backreference with named groups

Tags: java, regex, backreference, named-captures

How do you refer to named capture groups in Java's `String.replaceAll` method?

As a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, say I have the regex

```
\{(?<id>\d\d\d\d):(?<render>.*?)\}
```

which represents a tag in a string.  There can be multiple tags in a string, and I want to replace all tags with the contents of the "render" capture group.

If I have a string like

```
String test = "{0000:Billy} bites {0001:Jake}";
```

and want to get a result like `"Billy bites Jake"`, I know I can accomplish my goal with

```
test.replaceAll(tagRegex, "$2")
```

but I would like to be able to use something like

```
test.replaceAll(tagRegex, "$render")`
```

Is there a way to do this?  Using `"$render"` I get `IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/named_capturing_group_in_jdk7

you should use `${nameOfCapturedGroup}` which in your case would be `${render}`.

DEMO:

```
String test = "{0000:Billy} bites {0001:Jake}";
test = test.replaceAll("\\{(?<id>\\d\\d\\d\\d):(?<render>.*?)\\}", "${render}");
System.out.println(test);
```

Output: `Billy bites Jake`